# Constraints to take care of different iPhone/iPad sizes for images xcode 7 beta 4

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, ipad

I'm new to iOS development, so setting constraints for objects on the storyboard in Xcode has been difficult for me.

As this picture below shows, I have 3 borders for buttons I created in sketch so they are all images, each of them inside of a image view:

[image: screenshot]

I tried adding constraints by pinning all three images to the left, right and below themselves but I got errors for it and it did not come out right at all on the simulators. All of the images are in aspect fill mode, and I have the view in the size of an iPhone 4 when I put the images in the storyboard. Here's an example of what it looks like in the iPhone 6 simulator without any constraints:

[image: screenshot]

What are the constraints I need so that it looks okay for all iPhone and iPad sizes and looks like it does in the storyboard? And landscape mode will not be a part of this application, so that will not need to be accounted for.

Comment: Try to center all three views (while all of them are selected) and then "Add Missing Contraints." Side note, don't use the strategy you are currently using for UIButton boarders. Look up how to create custom boarders though the IB or even programmatically. Your current setup is very messy and not good practice.

Comment: I agree with @Caleb. The while problem is that you have created borders for buttons as image views. That's not how you do it. If you have an image for a button, make it the button's background image.

Comment: Yeah I figured it wasn't right, I changed it to all buttons with borders programmatically but it still isn't working. See comment to picture answer below. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

[image]

You can also use button 1 equal width constraint
and button 2 equal width constraint

For more details http://www.raywenderlich.com/83129/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-swift-part-1

[image]

Which is your requirement???

Comment: So I changed the images to actual buttons with borders programmatically like the others said and I used your constraints and got these errors:  http://s5.postimg.org/45xczyc3r/Screen_Shot_2015_08_04_at_12_34_41_AM.png                                                                                                                  This is how it comes out in the 4s for example: http://s5.postimg.org/taodddbk7/Screen_Shot_2015_08_04_at_12_35_11_AM.png         it still doesn't look right and when I changed the view to 3.5 inch like you said, the long bottom button gets covered as it all moves down

Comment: There is also a "Preview" functionality (split window left and right) where you can add simulated devices in various sizes (by clicking the button with the two intersecting circles, and choosing "Preview (1)" from the navigation breadcrumb's leftmost drop-down menu).