# Xcode LaunchScreen.storyboard

Tags: xcode, storyboard, launch-screen

So I created a LaunchScreen.storyboard for my launch images.  Thing is, after I added the storyboard, the buttons on my main.storyboard are altered and smushed together when I run the simulator.  My AdMob banner at the bottom also becomes smaller and the edges transparent (see screenshots)

Before LaunchScreen.storyboard added:
[image]

After LaunchScreen.storyboard added:
[image]

Does anybody know why my LaunchScreen.storyboard is causing this alteration and how would I fix it so it looks normal again when I run the simulator?

Much appreciated!

Comment: Try adding constraint between buttons. Add vertical spacing constraint between buttons.

Comment: I've noticed that it isnt just the buttons that got altered but everything on my main.storyboard. man this is frustrating..

Comment: LaunchScreen behaves differently with different devices. It setup a screen size for a device. If you setup storyboard with 4" device and when you launch it on 4.7" device, it will be distorted.

Comment: So is there a way that I can use LaunchScreen on all devices and not have the images distorted?  Because from what I understand the whole purpose of using Launchscreen.storyboard is to avoid making different individual resolutions for different devices, is this incorrect?

Comment: @user2959094 take a look on my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31799888/constraints-to-take-care-of-different-iphone-ipad-sizes-for-images-xcode-7-beta/31800662#31800662

Comment: @user2959094 Launchscreen is already adjusted with constraints

Comment: I was able to adjust the buttons so that they aren't so close anymore, but I'm still trying to figure out the AdMob banner issue.  Before I added the LaunchScreen.storyboard the AdMob banner would fill the entire width of the simulator/phone.  After the Launch.Screen.storyboard was added, the banner is now smaller and now transparent.  I am running Smart Banner for it.  Does anybody know why the addition of the LaunchScreen.storyboard would affect the image of the AdMob banner?