# UIScrollView cross device UI compatibility

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiscrollview, xcode6

I am having trouble with my UI not resizing correctly to fit iphone 6 and 6s sizes correctly.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLiky.jpg This is what iphone 6 looks like. Constraints have made the logo at the top centered and the stop button at the bottom fill the entire width, and the UIScrollView fill the entire width, but the buttons inside the actual UIScrollView do not fill the entire width.

I designed the interface using storyboard, interface builder, using the screen size of 4 inches. This is what iphone 4 inch looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJqMN.png.

Comment: This may help u http://www.raywenderlich.com/83129/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-swift-part-1    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31799888/constraints-to-take-care-of-different-iphone-ipad-sizes-for-images-xcode-7-beta/31800662#31800662

Comment: I know this isn't really an answer but you may want to try using a collection view instead.

Comment: I'm trying that right now aasatt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your scroll view contain a single child that holds all of those cells, or are they all children of the scroll view? It's easiest if a scroll view has a single child, because then all you have to do is constrain the child's four edges to the scroll view's, then constrain the child's width to equal the width of the scroll view. This will make the contents shrink or stretch to fill the entire width of the screen on all devices.

Comment: They are all children of the UIScrollView. I will create a content view inside the scroll view to hold all the buttons. How do I constrain the child's four edges to the scroll views? But what about the buttons inside the content view? How do I constrain them to be "pinned" to the sides of the content view? Forgive me, I'm new to constraints

Comment: Nevermind I did some messing around and reading and got it thanks to you