# How to Resize UiButtons to fit on any iPhone Screen Size

Tags: objective-c, autolayout, size-classes

I made an app (using storyboard) that fits the screen of iPhone 6. So when I tested it in iPhone 5 it becomes different.

I enabled auto layout and size classes but I don't know how I can use them to make this work.

How can I make the buttons (Event, Dialled, Missed, and Received) resize to fit on other iPhone screen sizes.

[image]

Comment: Select your blue view. and add constraints to it like here discussed in detail:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/34368263/4272498

Comment: basics of autolayout and constraints http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31799888/constraints-to-take-care-of-different-iphone-ipad-sizes-for-images-xcode-7-beta/31800662#31800662

Comment: Is the blue bar a subview of the table view, or a sibling of it? Post a screen shot of that scene's section in the document outline, with all the disclosure triangles turned down.

Comment: @Irfan you saved me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the UITableView is is missing some basic constraints. Or there are other constraints, that block others. (i.e. fixed width constraint)

This is how it should be:
[image: constrains]

Simple.